# Mounting motherboard but power led not ligting up

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I have bought a motherboard and I mounted it on my case. I connected all the wires that is Power switch, Reset switch, HDD LED but the problem is when connecting power LED and ground. The power LED wire is a single green wire and the ground wire is a single black wire. I tried connecting the power LED but when I power my computer it does not light, I think I should connect the ground wire too but I don't know how to do it.

My motherboard is [MSI G31M3-F V2](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/G31M3-F-V2--3-Audio-Ports-.html#/?div=Manual). Can anyone help me to connect the ground wire?

Answer (score 3):

Both must be connected. Connect the ground to the - pin and the other to the + pin.

Answer (score 0):

On page 7 of your motherboard manual there is a diagram for the `Front Panel Connectors`; specifically the group of pins labeled `JFP1` (it is where you plugged in the HDD LED & power/reset switches).

The diagram shows a `+` and a `-` next to each pin for each of the LEDs/Switches. The single green wire is the positive (`+`) wire, and the black is ground (`-`); both must be connected for the LED to function.

Because LEDs are diodes, they only allow current to pass though one way; this is why the wires need to be connected in the "right direction" unlike a switch where polarity does not matter.